# Angular 8 Pagination: How can I translate 'of'?

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material, angular8

I would like to translate the Paginator provided by `Angular Material`. I know I can access all of the labels in the `_intl` property of the Paginator Object:

```js
_intl: MatPaginatorIntl
changes: Subject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(1), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
itemsPerPageLabel: "Kunden pro Seite"
nextPageLabel: "Next page"
previousPageLabel: "Previous page"
firstPageLabel: "First page"
lastPageLabel: "Last page"
getRangeLabel: (page, pageSize, length) => {…}
```

but how can I translate 'of'?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what `getRangeLabel` does. You format the label based on the input.

```
getRangeLabel: (page, pageSize, length) => {return 'your label here based on input'; }
```